Socket io not listening to events
I'm using node.js and socket.io v4.8.0. I'm trying to create a basic chat application that updates my postgress db once an event such as "send message" has been called. I am able to establish a connection. However whenever I try to listen to an event the callback function is never triggered.
My client side and server side version match too both being v4+

import express from "express";
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import { authMiddleware } from "./middleware";
import { createServer } from "http";
import { getDb } from "./db";
import { chatParticipant, message } from "./schema";
import { and, eq } from "drizzle-orm";

const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer);
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const db = getDb();

app.use(authMiddleware);

app.use(express.json());

const INACTIVITY_TIMEOUT = 10 * 60 * 1000;

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("A user connected");

  let currentChatId: number | null = null;
  let currentUserId: string | null = null;
  let inactivityTimer: NodeJS.Timeout | null = null;

  function resetInactivityTimer() {
    if (inactivityTimer) {
      clearTimeout(inactivityTimer);
    }
    inactivityTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`Closing inactive connection for user ${currentUserId}`);
      socket.disconnect(true);
    }, INACTIVITY_TIMEOUT);
  }

  resetInactivityTimer();

  socket.on("join chat", async (chatId: number, userId: string) => {
    console.log("join chat", chatId, userId);
    resetInactivityTimer();
    try {
      const userChatParticipant = await db.query.chatParticipant.findFirst({
        where: and(
          eq(chatParticipant.chatId, chatId),
          eq(chatParticipant.userId, userId)
        ),
      });

      if (!userChatParticipant) {
        socket.emit("error", "You are not a participant of this chat");
        return;
      }

      currentChatId = chatId;
      currentUserId = userId;
      socket.join(`chat_${chatId}`);
      console.log(`User ${userId} joined chat ${chatId}`);

      const recentMessages = await db
        .select()
        .from(message)
        .where(eq(message.chatId, chatId))
        .orderBy(message.createdAt)
        .limit(50);

      socket.emit("recent messages", recentMessages);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error joining chat:", error);
      socket.emit("error", "An error occurred while joining the chat");
    }
  });

  socket.on("leave chat", () => {
    resetInactivityTimer();
    if (currentChatId && currentUserId) {
      socket.leave(`chat_${currentChatId}`);
      console.log(`User ${currentUserId} left chat ${currentChatId}`);
      currentChatId = null;
      currentUserId = null;
    }
  });

  socket.on("send message", async (content: string) => {
    resetInactivityTimer();
    if (!currentChatId || !currentUserId) {
      socket.emit("error", "You are not in a chat room");
      return;
    }

    try {
      const [newMessage] = await db
        .insert(message)
        .values({
          senderId: currentUserId,
          chatId: currentChatId,
          content,
        })
        .returning();

      io.to(`chat_${currentChatId}`).emit("new message", {
        ...newMessage,
        content: newMessage.content,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error sending message:", error);
      socket.emit("error", "An error occurred while sending the message");
    }
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("User disconnected");
    if (inactivityTimer) {
      clearTimeout(inactivityTimer);
    }
  });
});

// Start the server
httpServer.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});```


Expecting the console logs to be logged and the database to be updated/queried.


I have not tested in a dev environment, but afaik the socket object will only live as long as the io.on('connection',...) is being executed. Afterwards the object socket should be destroyed and with it, its handlers. I assume you need to rewrite your code to handle the socket and e.g. currentChatId outside of the io.on(...) handler e.g. by maintaining an object or array.
